# Улучшить имя переменной indexWordEnd

Tags: переменные, любой-язык

Назвал переменную вот так: `indexWordEnd`

Насколько это хорошее имя переменной? Может есть вариант получше?

Интересуют только нормальные имена переменных (то есть вариант `ifhghnnfcr764576fghfjhtr6itgfgfu6tutgygfkut7` **не подойдет**).

Как можно догадаться, эта переменная представляет целое неотрицательное число, индекс окончания слова в тексте.

Comment: `ifhghnnfcr764576fghfjhtr6itgfgfu6tutgygfkut7` сойдет? :)

Comment: Смотря для чего

Comment: не, это фигня. Вот МОЩЬ: `SelectElementWithTopLeftLightBrownBorderAndRedBackgroundTenPixelsBlackBoxShadowAndOnePixelsBlurred`

Comment: `unsignedIndexWordEnd`

Comment: `i` — лучшая переменная

Comment: Серьёзно? Вам нужна помощь экспертов, чтобы придумать имя переменной? Если это шутка, то неудачная.

Comment: @Александр, ну оно мне правда не очень нравится. Я хочу заменить его на `start`, но тогда оно станет чуть менее понятным. Вот и спросил.

Comment: В любом случае это не тот вопрос, который следует задавать на SO

Comment: По правилам английского скорее `wordEndIndex` или допустим `wordEndPosition`.

Comment: нормальное название